# Find the equation of a tangent line at $(3,-1)$ on the circle $x^2+y^2+2x-y-17=o$

Tags: circles, implicit-differentiation

Determine the equations of tangents from point $A( 3 , -1)$ to circle (C) of equation: $x^2+y^2+4x+8y+3=0$ Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you write the equation of the circle in standard form?  Do you know implicit differentiation?

Comment: You can write the eq of circle in standard form and about implicit differentiation I've never heard of it :/ still in grade 11

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$x^2+4x+y^2+8y+3=0\implies (x+2)^2+(y+4)^2=17$$

Let $\;(a,b)\;$ one of the tangency points on the circle, then if the wanted line is

$$y+1=m(x-3)\iff y=mx-3m-1\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

it must be that

$$m\cdot\frac35=-1\iff m=-\frac53\;\;\text{(why?)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2+4x+8y+3=0$$
Apply the derivative w.r.t. x to both sides:
$$2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}+4+8\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
Now we make $\frac{dy}{dx}$ the subject of the formula:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}(2y+8)=-2x-4$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-2x-4}{2y+8}$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{x+2}{y+4}$$
Now we insert $(x,y)=(3,-1)$ and find the slope of the tangent line
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{5}{3}$$
Now that we have the slope, we can find the equation of the line as we know it passes through the point
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
$$y-1=-\dfrac{5}{3}(x-3)$$
$$y-1=-\dfrac{5x-15}{3}$$
$$y-1=-\dfrac{5x}{3}+5$$
$$y=-\dfrac{5x}{3}+6$$
And theres the equation for your line!

Comment: Watch it: the given point is $\;(3,\color{red}{-1})\;$ ...

Comment: oh sorry, i shall edit my answer